# Flutter- How to hold Camera in Screen after clicking photos?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to hold the camera screen after clicking the image in the flutter.
Now I am holding the image using container, but its displaying mirror image.
`Container( 
 child: 
Center(child: 
Image.file(new File(imagePath)))),`

```
return new AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
    child: new CameraPreview(controller),
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Stack view with preview controller and list to display the captured images list and capture button to capture image.

Add the path to list, use the same list to populate in list view. after taking the no of pictures you need to have a submit button to pop the view.
here is the sample code [camera_view_sample_code](https://gist.github.com/aravindhkumar23/739cf778e31fa48f4f38c7494066d721)